# Cutting text from file

Tags: php, file

I have the following text file:

```
::: Student Exam :::
Name: John Cage
Score: 5
Witness: Maria McCain
::: End Exam :::

::: Student Exam :::
Name: John Cage
Score: 5
Witness: Calvin Gilbert
::: End Exam :::
```

I'm parsing it using this code:

```
$db = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/exams.txt', TRUE);
$nl = "\r\n";

preg_match_all("|::: Student Exam :::(.*?)::: End Exam :::|s", $db, $exams);

foreach($exams[1] as $exam) {
    preg_match("|Name: (.*?)$nl|s", $exam, $name);
    preg_match("|Score: (.*?)$nl|s", $exam, $score);
    preg_match("|Witness: (.*?)$nl|s", $exam, $witness);

    if($score[1] < 4) {
        // Something Here
    }
}
```

I need, if the score is under `4`, the exam must be removed from the file. How this can be done?

Comment: Why not a database ? This will be really hard to maintain as your application scales.

Comment: I don't think so. I already have $exams variable, I can just save it to the same file, after the end of the script. But I want to keep only the higher score exams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty array

```
$goodExams = array()
```

And push exams into it:

```
if($score[1] >= 4) {
    $goodExams[] = $exam;
}
```

Or:

```
if($score[1] >= 4) {
    $goodExams[] = array('name' => $name[1], 'score'=>$score[1], 'witness'=>$witness[1]);
}

$newTxt = "";
foreach($goodExams as $exam){
    $newTxt.="::: Student Exam :::" . PHP_EOL;

    // concatenae your data here

    $newTxt.="::: End Exam :::" . PHP_EOL;
}

file_put_contents($filename, $newTxt)
```

After that you can process the goodExams array and dump your textfile.